# How do I delete a file with it's public url in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, file

In my controller, I store images in my public folder like this:

```
//...
$fileName = $request->all()["image"]->store("/images", "public");
$user->image_url = Storage::url($fileName);
$user->save();
```

Now, When a user wants to change their profile pic, I want to delete the image:

```
// $user->image_url looks like: /storage/images/ZVw3jm8Y4k2mx59DGouz.jpg
Storage::delete($user->image_url, "public");
```

But the above code is not deleting the image. Please, what is the right way?

Comment: I finally was able to delete the images using 
     `Storage::disk("public")->delete("images" . "/" . basename($user->image_url));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

> **Ensure your file is stored in `storage` or `public`**. If the public use [`public_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-public-path) if storage use [`storage_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-storage-path)

File Delete

```
$deletedFile = File::delete(storage_path('file_name'));
```

`unlink` method

```
$filedeleted = unlink(public_path('file_name'));
```

---

Always use `file_exists` before performing the deleting action.

```
if (file_exists( storage_path('file_name') )){}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ran the code and discovered it was `public_path` that resolved to the correct path. Likely due to the fact that I was storing the images with `store("images", "public")` So `public_path($user->image_url)` not `storage_path($user->image_url)` resolved to the right path.